# Why certificate is not a secret in SSL authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl, digital-certificate

I'm reading about [certificate-based authentication in SSL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication), and got a question about this process. (picture is taken from above link)

[image]

Question is: why `server.cer` and `client.cer` are not secrets. In this diagram, it seems that communication hasn't been encrypted when certs got exchanged, does this mean both certificates are exposed in plaintext? If so, why it's secure? Because in this way an adversary can easily obtain server's public key as well as its certificate, and impersonate the server. I think I misunderstood something. Please correct me.

Comment: *easily obtain server's public key as well as its certificate,* - you make that sound like those were two distinct things. But the certificate essentially **is** the public key plus a few attributes. Especially it is **not** the private key. To impersonate the server, you still need the private key.

Comment: @mkl I mean given that the certificate is used to verify the public key belongs to the server, if an adversary can obtain both public key and certificate, clients would have no way to distinguish it from an real server, wouldn't they?

Comment: The certificate *is* the public key plus some extra, public information. You can of course present any certificate to try and impersonate, but as you don't have the private key, you cannot communicate as that impersonated entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Because in this way an adversary can easily obtain server's public key as well as its certificate

Correct.

> and impersonate the server.

Incorrect. You need the private key as well as the certificate to impersonate the server.

The diagram you quoted isn't correct. Both sides will have not only a keystore but a truststore. The incoming certificates are checked against the local truststore; the outgoing certificate comes from the keystore.

> given that the certificate is used to verify the public key belongs to the server

No. The certificate *plus its digital signature* is used to verify that the *certificate* belongs to the server. The digital signature is created with the private key. See the article you quoted.

However it isn't entirely correct. In the diagram, incoming certificates are checked against a local *truststore,* which is separate from the keystore. The session key is never exchanged (2.1 step 5).

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I think certificate is signed by CA with CA's private key and user can verify it with CA's public key. How is this related to server's private key.

Comment: The server sends a digital signature signed by its own private key. The client does the same, in the `CertificateVerify` message. It's all in the article you cited. This is in addition to the CA signing.